# Codes on onBindViewHolder runs before data fetched: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5

Tags: java, android, api

I'm using news api which fetches 20 news at a time. I only want to keep 5 for each fetch in my android app. I want to support fetching news from several countries. Example behaviour: articles list contains 5 articles from US and 5 articles from Japan. The first 'news message' should show 5 news from the US. The next 'news message' should show 5 articles from Japan. But the US ones should still be there. Fetching once works fine. I have difficulty showing 10 articles from fetching twice.

```
public void fetchArticlesFromAPI(String country){
        toggleLoading(true);
        articlesServices.getArticles(country, ArticlesApiClient.NEWS_KEY)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(this::articlesSuccessResponse)
                .doOnError(this::articlesErrorResponse)
                .subscribe(new Observer<ArticlesList>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ArticlesList articlesList) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });
}
```

```
private void articlesSuccessResponse(ArticlesList articles) {
        toggleLoading(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            articlesList.add(articles.getArticle().get(i));
        }
        mAdapter.setArticlesList(articlesList);
        
        // add news message part
        String countryLongForm = countryMap.get(country) != null ?  countryMap.get(country) + " " : "";
        Message responseMessage = new Message("Top headline "  + countryLongForm + "articles fetched:",
                "news", false);
        messageArrayList.add(responseMessage);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

```
int news = 0;

public void setArticlesList (ArrayList<Article> articlesList) {
    this.articlesList = articlesList;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);

        switch (message.getType()) {
            case "news":
                ((ArticlesViewHolder) holder).message.setText(message.getMessage());

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Article model = articlesList.get(news + i); // ***** source of error
                    // ... layout of view holder
                }
                news = news + 5;
                break;
        }
}
```

I keep getting

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.demo.chatbot.MessageAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:175)
```

I tried adding something like `if (isNewsFetched) {}` to ensure articles are fetched before adding the 'news message'. I tried moving the 'add message' part to onComplete. But still the same error.

The number of articles fetching the second time should be 10 so `news + i` should run from 5 to 9... I don't get why I have this error.

Comment: Please attach Adapter's method `setArticlesList` logic in the question as well.

Comment: Where is your articlesList initialization? I mean articlesList not in adapter, but in Activity/Fragment

Comment: @Hetfieldan24, I have `private ArrayList<Article> articlesList;` before onCreate and `articlesList = new ArrayList<Article>();` in onCreate.